# Triggering RelayCommand from code-behind

Tags: c#, mvvm-light

I have a Main Page for my application that is formed froma  number of other windows. One of which is the settings for my applications and is open/closed by clicking a button from my Main Page. This window has a View Model as well as two buttons, Save and Cancel. Pressing Cancel is used to restore the previous settings and Save just stores them. Now, when I use the main menu to close the Properties I want the Cancel to be called and am wondering about the best way to do this.

So in my view model I have something like this:

```
public RelayCommand CancelRC { get; private set; }

public  PropertiesViewModel
{
    CancelRC = new RelayCommand(RestoreProperties)
}

private RestoreProperties
{
     // Restore
}
```

In my MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private void Properties_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (PropertiesForm.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
    {
        PropertiesForm.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        PropertiesForm.IsSelected = true;
    }
    else
    {
        PropertiesForm.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        IncidentForm.IsSelected = true;

        // Send a Cancel relaycommand to the Properties View Model?
    }
}
```

The obvious solution to me is to trigger the RelayCommand manually but I am not sure this is the most appropriate way to do it and I am not sure how you would trigger that anyway. So it this the way to do it or is there a more preferred way to do something like this?

Similarly is manually hiding and showing the Properties via the Main Page like this the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the Properties_Click method and in your xaml do the following:

```
<Button Command="{Binding CancelRC}">Properties</Button>
```

This will cause the button to use RelayCommand.CanExecute and RelayCommand.Execute with no code on your part.  The code assumes the window datacontext is set to your View Model.

Comment: Sounds interesting, I didn't know that was possible. Does that mean all of the Galasoft `EventtoCommand` stuff is unnecessary? But I am not totally sure that will help with regards to what the button handler needs to do with regards to hiding and showing the window. The `CanExecute` and `Execute` are these what are used to programmatically drive a `RelayCommand`? I guess that would still mean the main page would need to either directly access the View Model or send a message to it anyway?

Comment: The Galasoft EventToCommand is very useful. The main window wouldn't necessarily need to access the properties window view model, instead you could have a view model for the main page and let the two view models either know about or message with each other.  "Ideally" in MVVM View Models should be controlling the views, to include what to show, visibility, application flow, etc.  You can bind the windows visibility to a property in the View Model, either directly or with a property converter.

Comment: That's similar to what I did in the end. I meant, badly said though, that the EventToCommand is unnecessary for Buttons on Silverlight it appears from using it as per your answer. Your comment + answer means I have accepted this. Thanks!